# Qt: Regex max. 9 digits (Int and Float)

Tags: regex, qt

I want to have a regex for:
 - integer
 - float
 - max. 9 Digits

It is for Qt5

```
^[\d*[.,]?\d+]{0,4}$
```

without the {0,4} the regex works fine.
This Version works perfect, but i want to have max 9 digits

```
\d*[.,]?\d+
```

Comment: Your `^[\d*[.,]?\d+]{0,4}$` pattern is "corrupt", it [matches](https://regex101.com/r/ZaKZHu/1) strings that start with an optional digit, `*`, `,`, `.` or `[` and then have 0 to 4 digits. And see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56455482/3832970) for the generic solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
^(?!(?:\D*\d){10})\d*[.,]?\d+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Hb8EfG/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%3F!(%3F%3A%5CD*%5Cd)%7B10%7D)%5Cd*%5B.%2C%5D%3F%5Cd%2B%24):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - string start
- `(?!(?:\D*\d){10})` - fail the match if 10 or more digits is found
- `\d*` - 0+ digits
- `[.,]?` - an optional `.` or `,`
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit complicated. I'm also not so sure about the expression we would be wishing to design here, I'm guessing, we might want integers or floats with four digits, then we would be starting with a simple expression such as:

```
^\d{1,5}\.\d{1,4}$|^\d{1,9}$
```

The problem here would be this expression would also fail `111111.1`, which is just one thing that would create sophistication. Another thing is that if we wish to also include commas.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/18uyN3/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Your pattern would not match `123,45678`

Answer (score 0):

Like Emma said, its complicated.

My suggestions is

```
(^\d{1}[,.]\d{1,8}$)|(^\d{2}[,.]\d{1,7}$)|(^\d{3}[,.]\d{1,6}$)|(^\d{4}[,.]\d{1,5}$)|(^\d{5}[,.]\d{1,4}$)|(^\d{6}[,.]\d{1,3}$)|(^\d{7}[,.]\d{1,2}$)|(^\d{8}[,.]\d{1,1}$)|(^\d{1,9}$)
```

First group checks all floats with one digit before the decimal point and 1 to 8 decimal places
Second group checks all floats with two digits before the decimal point and 1 to 7 decimal places
Third group checks all flaots with three digits before the decimal point and 1 to 6 decimal places
And so on...
The last group checks all integers with 1 to 9 digits

W/o `^` and `$` in each group, it found the last 9 numbers in a 9+ digits number when using the multi line flag

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=(%5E%5Cd%7B1%7D%5B%2C.%5D%5Cd%7B1%2C8%7D%24)%7C(%5E%5Cd%7B2%7D%5B%2C.%5D%5Cd%7B1%2C7%7D%24)%7C(%5E%5Cd%7B3%7D%5B%2C.%5D%5Cd%7B1%2C6%7D%24)%7C(%5E%5Cd%7B4%7D%5B%2C.%5D%5Cd%7B1%2C5%7D%24)%7C(%5E%5Cd%7B5%7D%5B%2C.%5D%5Cd%7B1%2C4%7D%24)%7C(%5E%5Cd%7B6%7D%5B%2C.%5D%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%24)%7C(%5E%5Cd%7B7%7D%5B%2C.%5D%5Cd%7B1%2C2%7D%24)%7C(%5E%5Cd%7B8%7D%5B%2C.%5D%5Cd%7B1%2C1%7D%24)%7C(%5E%5Cd%7B1%2C9%7D%24))